# c++ best way to store arrays or vectors of objects on disk for a simple database

Tags: c++, storage

I've been working on a PVR backend for scheduling TV recordings and I'm trying to figure out the best way to keep a simple database with all of the relevant information in it. I put together a lazy man's prototype (shown below), but I don't want to statically allocate huge arrays and then simply dump the contents of ram for those objects to disk for storage.

What is my best option given the following lazy/bad practice prototypes? How would an experienced programmer choose to do something like this? If I was going to do it all without using toString/fromString functions, how would I do it?

```
struct Recording{
    Date date;
    int channel;
    int length; //length in hours, minutes, or seconds
    bool is_interlaced; //if true, denotes that the episode is interlaced
    bool done; //if true, denotes that the episode has been recorded
    bool record_successful; //Currently unused
};

struct TV_Episode{
    struct Recording recording;
    char title[128]; //Episode Title
    char season; //Season number
    char episode; //Episode number
};

struct TV_Show{
    char name[64]; //TV Show name
    char numepisodes; //The number of episodes in the array
    struct TV_Episode episodes[100]; //Array containing airings of a TV show
};

struct Movie{
    struct Recording recording;
    char title[128]; //Movie Title, optionally including the year in brackets
};

struct Recordings_DB{ /*
    * Obviously these types can be done away with using inheritance
    * and the Recordings_DB type can be done away with using a vector.
    * They are just here to illustrate the concept.
    */
    struct TV_Show shows[20];
    struct Movie movies[20];
};
```

Comment: Consider something like XML or JSON and learn to serialize to/from that.  The advantages are you have a file that's structured but still human readable while you're figuring stuff out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually worked in the PVR set-top box world for 5+ years and at my old company we were faced with a similar choice. Since your intent is to store the PVR recordings on disk, here are some of the approaches you can take -

1. **Binary Protocol:** Dump the C or C++ POD types to a binary file. This will require a custom parser with difficult to maintain compatibility when adding/deleting fields. Also not human readable, so debugging will be a pain. If you do go this route for speed or disk usage reasons, at least use Google's [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) as the binary protocol.
2. **Serialized Protocol** Use a human readable protocol like XML, JSON to serialize the data to/from disk. Easy to debug and also to add/remove fields to the schema. Lots of opensource parsers are available e.g. expat, libxml2, rapidjson, json-c that can do the heavy lifting for you.
3. **Embedded Database** If your system needs to support sort, search, filtering, etc. I highly recommend [SQlite](http://www.sqlite.org/), a lightweight database suitable for embedded platforms with native C interface. This option requires more development effort upfront but will scale better as your system evolves.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I appreciate it. I haven't been programming for awhile, so I'm quite rusty, and I never did much in the way of high level stuff anyway. Are there any good beginner SQL tutorials for C++ that you would recommend? (I have used SQL in the past, but it was with PHP, not C/C++)

Comment: [Definitive Guide To Sqlite](http://www.amazon.com/Definitive-Guide-SQLite-Experts-Source/dp/1430232250/) is a solid book to get in depth knowledge and best coding practices for SQLite's C interface. I haven't used a lot of tutorials but this [online tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm) looks promising.

Comment: Thanks for the info and for the inclusion of the Amazon link as I usually order from them anyway. I have just ordered two books on SQL and I think I will order this one when I have finished the other two. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to statically allocate arrays, then why not use `std::string` and `std::vector`? You get dynamic allocation to the correct size, and you get no limit on the maximum size. It's a win win.

Also don't use `char` for integer values. That kind of penny pinching is unnecessary. It will only come back to bite you. Remember Y2K? Believe it or not modern computers have lots of memory and disk space. And in many cases, because of padding, you're not actually saving any memory anyway.

Comment: Using char was more for kicks and playing with casting again. However, I meant store, as in, store on the disk. Also, the char arrays were more so that I could write a scheme that I could, if I really wanted to, just dump the entire memory space to the hard drive and have it work while I looked for a better option (hence this post)

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be a little annoying, as you'll either need to write your own serialization code (tostring/fromstring) or adopt a library. If you write your own, make sure to think about the case where you add a field to one of your structs but want to be able to read in the old format; planning ahead helps a lot with that problem.

Two choices you might consider are Google's protocol buffers library (you would define protocol buffers instead of structs, and then you can just serialize the top-level RecordingsDB) or SQLite (you would have to write some basic SQL to fill in the fields, but you also get indexing and transactions). If your database is never going to be more than a few thousand records, I recommend protocol buffers as SQL is not going to get you much benefit. Both are reasonably compact, simple libraries that are well supported.